# Какие труды необходимо изучить для знакомства с системой древнерусского языка?

Tags: грамматика, недопустимая-метка, история, старая-грамматика, источники

Добрый день! Я задался целью изучить грамматику (имеется в виду полное описание системы языка: фонетики, морфемики, морфологии, словообразования, синтаксиса и основных вещей, связанных с лексикой).

В этой связи наткнулся на большое разнообразие трудов на данную тему: одни из них общие, другие — частные; одни — научные, другие — научно-популярные, третьи — явно лженаучные или псевдонаучные. Кроме того, зная как у нас зачастую делается "наука" — переливанием из пустого в порожнее и изданием под своей подписью, — видимо даже среди научных изложений данной темы есть труды важные и корневые, а есть посредственные.

Что посоветуете изучить и в какой последовательности? Основные приоритеты:

- строгая научность (научно-популярные и популярные работы не интересуют);
- системное рассмотрение разных языковых явлений и механизмов (фонетики, морфемики, морфологии, словообразования, синтаксиса) в рамках одного труда;
- общепризнанность, или, во всяком случае, максимально широкое признание излагаемой концепции.

Кроме того, был бы благодарен, если бы вы посоветовали мне также работы, связанные с развитием древнерусского языка в современные восточнославянские языки.

Спасибо.

Comment: Что-то Вы замахнулись... Возьмите любой учебник просто старославянского языка. Если осилите, сами поймете, что дальше делать. А для начала, разберитесь вообще, что такое древнерусский язык, чем он отличается от старославянского, например.

Comment: @shampar, большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @behemothus, извините, но вопрос был о древнерусском языке, а не о старославянском. Причем вопрос был весьма конкретный. Про "любой учебник" - очень ценный совет! "Замахнулись" - не комментирую.

Comment: Уважаемый vyshkant, behemothus абсолютно прав. Возможно, есть основание начать изучение именно с грамматики старославянского языка, и это будет логично Успехов Вам в изучении.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53253/discussion-on-question-by-vyshkant------).

Comment: @user183861 Да всё проще. "Древнерусский" язык - и есть старославянский (так называемого "древнерусского извода"), никаких других "древнерусских" не существует. Как минимум - в виде пригодном для изучения, просто текстов нет сохранившихся (видимо, и не было). Собственно древнерусский частично реконстуируется только по вкраплениям руссицизмов в тот самый "древнерусский извод". Но и эти отличия, судя по всему - минимальны. И второе. Автор явно не понимает, что полностью изучить, например, грамматику (тем более - с нуля) невозможно в принципе. А у него это - лишь часть заявленной работы.

Answer (score 1):

Есть серия исследований ИРЯ им. В.В. Виноградова «Историческая грамматика древнерусского языка» под ред. В.Б. Крысько. Издавалась Азбуковником с 2000 года. Знаю, что в 2006 г. вышел IV том о числительных (он у меня в руках). Замечательный труд.

Answer (score 0):

Курс лекций исторической грамматики можно скачать

http://listid.ru/item/1415238.html

http://www.nsu.ru/xmlui/handle/nsu/1145

http://kgu-journalist.ucoz.ru/load/4-1-0-82

http://gendocs.ru/v7011/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%

http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/6062855/

Comment: Людмила, настоятельная просьба не давать больше ссылок на непроверенные источники. По первой ссылке можно скачать разве что кучу вирусов. Остальные не проверял, ибо и так полдня потратил на чистку компьютера.

Answer (score 0):

*@user183861, поскольку комментарий отправлен модератором в чат, воспроизвожу его тут в виде ответа с небольшой редактурой.*

В том виде, как вопрос задан, он не имеет адекватного ответа.

Во-первых, "древнерусский" язык - и есть старославянский (так называемого "древнерусского извода"), никаких других "древнерусских" не существует. Как минимум - в виде пригодном для изучения, просто текстов нет сохранившихся (видимо, и не было). Собственно древнерусский частично реконструируется только по вкраплениям руссицизмов в тот самый "древнерусский извод". Но и эти отличия, судя по всему - минимальны.

И второе. Полностью изучить, например, грамматику (тем более - с нуля) невозможно в принципе. А у автора это - лишь часть заявленной работы.

> Как видно из ответа специалиста, все-таки "другие древнерусские"
>   существуют (в тексте ясно разграничены древнерусская редакция
>   старославянского и непосредственно древнерусский язык).

Из ответа специалиста видно лишь то, что существует некое понятие "древнерусского языка". Я против самого понятия не возражал.

Сам же разговор считаю вышедшим за пределы темы. Очевидно, что автор вопроса о таких вещах даже не подозревает. Он находится на начальной стадии изучения и того и другого.

PS
Хотите разобраться в разнице - открывайте отдельную тему.

Answer (score 0):

> Что посоветуете изучить и в какой последовательности?

Начните с азов. Именно с доступных учебников церковнославянского (Хабургаев, Ёлкина, Гаманович или любого другого). С отличиями потом разберетесь, они не критичны. Специальных учебников для начинающих древнерусского языка не существует. Более того, как верно сказал behemothus, основной инструмент изучения собственно "древнерусского" - исследования отличий древнерусской редакции (извода) ЦСЯ.

Создание же полной, как вы хотите, модели любого языка не под силу даже хорошо укомплектованной группе специалистов. Никто так никогда вопрос и не ставил.

Тут еще сложность в том, что для мертвого языка, почти не оставившего после себя письменных документов, построение даже частичной модели грамматики весьма затруднено. Сравните с так называемой "вульгарной латынью". О ней ведь почти ничего не известно в теоретическом плане.